# Trouble making searchbar responsive

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I have a searchbar in my header, which I need centered horizontally and just a little bit above the bottom of the header. I was able to achieve this by using

```
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
```

The problem I am having now is that although it is responsive when you make the window smaller horizontally, It is a total mess when you resize the window vertically. I am pretty sure it's because I used margin-top: 350px; to set the vertical position. I also would much rather not use flex display because it isn't supported by much yet. Below is a screenshot of how it looks normaly, and one of how it looks when the view is altered vertically. Also the code pertaining to it. If anyone could help me figure out how to get the searchbar to be responsive vertically, that would be great!

How it is normally:
[image]

How it looks when you change the screen size vertically (the searchbar is behind the images):
[image]

HTML:

```
<div class="outcont">
<div id="top" class="header">
<div class="wrap">
<div class="col1"><a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>" title="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?> - Return to the homepage"><img class="logoi" src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/main-logo.png" alt="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?> Logo" /></a></div>
<div class="col2"><?php wp_nav_menu(array('menu' => 'global-nav', 'container' => '')); ?></div>
</div>
<?php get_search_form(); ?>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#searchform div {
  shadow: 4px 7px 4px #000000;
  margin-top: 350px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#searchform .text {
  font-family: 'Merriweather';
  padding-left: 35px;
  height: 75px;
  width: 600px;
  font-size: 220%;
  color: #B7B7B7;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background: white url('images/search-img.png') no-repeat;
  background-position: 96% center;
}

#searchform .text:focus {
  background-image: none;
}

#searchform .text img {
  margin-right: 25px;
}
```

Comment: Flex is supported by 95% of all browsers. http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Answer (score 1):

Check out this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/msechrest/2z2aw5u0/6/) I have made for you.

I have my main div with a `background-image` and the input inside of that div with the css like so:

```
#hero {
    background: url('https://i.ytimg.com/vi/ReF6iQ7M5_A/maxresdefault.jpg') no-repeat center center scroll;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    right: 0;
}
#hero input {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: 34px;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    outline: none;
}
```

This way the textbox will always stay in the center of the image no matter how the browser is scaled. In order for this to work the textbox must have a defined width and height.

So in your case replace your css for the searchbox with the css I have for `#hero input` and set the parent divs position to relative with `position: relative;`.

Please let me know how this works out for you.

Hope this helps!